# Can I install Chromium OS on this pc, mediacom smartbook 144?

Tags: hardware-compatibility, chromium-os

I'd like to know if I could install Chromium OS on my [Mediacom Smartbook 144](https://www.mediacomeurope.it/Prodotti/Scheda.aspx?XRI=2905#SpecTec), with 4 GB RAM and an Intel Atom x5-z8350 CPU: would it run OK even if I also keep installed my version of Windows? And if so, how can I use it in dual boot mode?

Thank you to all who'll answer!

Comment: When it comes down RAM, you can try to optimize it a bit, a few words about that are here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromium/Tips_and_tricks

Answer (score 1):

The critical factor is that 32GB storage, not the CPU or RAM (although more RAM is always better). Fortunately, your machine will take an additional SSD SATA-III drive (see page 7 of your [Quick Guide](https://www.mediacomeurope.it/ZeusInc/PressRoom/Documents/Quick_Guide_M-SB144.pdf)), which installs with one Phillips head screwdriver.

Then, use a cloning app, like Clonezilla, to move Windows to the SSD drive, and when it works, you can remove the 32GB storage device (probably an MMC card).

After that's done, installing the Linux distro of your choice is easy; most distros' install process will give you an automatic option for side-by-side with Windows.